# Fatal server error: no screens found. Running linux distro from usb drive

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, netbook, x-windows, backtrack

I'm trying to run backtrack from a usb drive on my netbook.  Upon loading it, i get "Fatal server error: no screens found".  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these commands

```
fixvesa

startx
```

Comment: Huge thanks.  What was the cause and waht did this do?

Comment: graphic problem , mostly happen in live versions.